# Rendering a triangle using OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm having trouble getting a triangle to render on an Android device using OpenGL ES 3.0.

I'm using Google Nexus 5 for testing.
Below is my code - but all it renders is a blue screen (which is the clear color I have specified). I expect to see a red triangle but it isn't appearing.

Can someone please point out the flaw in my code? The shaders compile and link successfully.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(new TestSurfaceView(this));
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    private class TestSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer
    {
        private final String vertexShaderCode =
                "#version 300 es\n\n"+
                "in vec3 inPosition;\n" +
                "void main()\n" +
                "{\n" +
                " gl_Position = vec4(inPosition.xyz, 1.0);\n" +
                "}  \n";

        private final String fragmentShaderCode =
                "#version 300 es\n\n"+
                "out vec4 outColor;\n"+
                "void main()\n" +
                "{\n" +
                " outColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); \n" +
                "}  \n";

        public TestSurfaceView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            super.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
            setEGLContextClientVersion(3);
            setRenderer(this);
            setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
        {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3, 1);
        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
        {
            glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        }

        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
        {
            // States

            glClearColor(0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);                                                           // Set background to blue
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                                                                // Enable Depth Testing
            glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                                                                 // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do //TODO check
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);                                                                     // Enable Blending
            glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);                                      // The Type Of Blending To Do (for translucency)

            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
            glCullFace(GL_BACK);
            glActiveTexture(0);

            // Shaders

            int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderCode);
            glCompileShader(vertexShader);
            System.out.println("Vertex shader compile log:\n"+glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));

            int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderCode);
            glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
            System.out.println("Fragment shader compile log:\n"+glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));

            int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
            glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
            glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

            glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "inPosition");

            glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
            glValidateProgram(shaderProgram);
            System.out.println("Shader program validate log:\n"+glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
            glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

            // VAO

            float floatSize = Float.SIZE/8;
            float vertexSize = 3*floatSize;

            int[] arrays = new int[1];
            glGenVertexArrays(1, arrays, 0);
            int modelVao = arrays[0];
            glBindVertexArray(modelVao);

            int[] buffers = new int[3];
            glGenBuffers(3, buffers, 0);

            int modelVertexVbo = buffers[0];
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, modelVertexVbo);

            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (int)(vertexSize*3f), null, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

            // Triangle

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, modelVertexVbo);
            ByteBuffer b = (ByteBuffer)glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, (int)(vertexSize*3), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);

            b.putFloat(-1f);
            b.putFloat(1f);
            b.putFloat(0f);

            b.putFloat(-1f);
            b.putFloat(-1f);
            b.putFloat(0f);

            b.putFloat(1f);
            b.putFloat(-1f);
            b.putFloat(0f);

            b.flip();
            glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }
    }
}
```

My manifest is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: `glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1, 1);` The second parameter means "use 1 vertex" which isn't enough to specify a triangle. Also, if you are rendering one instance, don't bother with the instanced function.

Comment: Thanks for the response Colonel Thirty Two. You're right it should be '3' not '1'.

I tried changing it to glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3, 1); but no luck, still a blue screen without a triangle.

I'm using glDrawArraysInstanced because I'll be using instancing (not yet but will be). I also tried glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3) and same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You enable backface culling in `onSurfaceCreated()`:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

The default winding order for front faces in OpenGL is counter-clockwise. This means that if you enable backface culling, all triangles with clockwise winding are eliminated. So the triangle in your code will not be rendered because it has clockwise winding:

```
(1f, -1f, 0f)
(-1f, -1f, 0f)
(-1f, 1f, 0f)
```

In ASCII art, the triangle looks like this, with vertices numbered from 0 to 2:

```
2
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
1-----0
```

You can tell that the winding is clockwise if you follow the vertices in index order.

Comment: Hi Reto Koradi, thanks for your answer. The counter clock-wise ordering was indeed an issue - thanks for pointing it out.

However, even after swapping the order to:

(-1f, 1f, 0f)
(-1f, -1f, 0f)
(1f, -1f, 0f)

I'm still out of luck - just a blue screen.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Reto Koradi and Colonel Thirty Two for finding two important flaws with my code.
The last flaw I found was that I needed to specify native ordering of the byte buffer obtained from **glMapBufferRange** before writing to it.

```
ByteBuffer b = (ByteBuffer)glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, (int)(vertexSize*3), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);
b.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
```